# How to convert 09 MySQL Query into a single query

Tags: php, mysql

How can i convert this query into a single query or suggest me how can i insert them into database. Please correct me if there is any coding mistake.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tec") or     die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
$saveweave = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'saveweave');
if(isset($saveweave)){
$roll = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, filter_input(INPUT_POST,'roll'));
$libtutfee = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, filter_input(INPUT_POST,'libtutfee'));
$libsemno = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, filter_input(INPUT_POST,'libsemno'));
$reference = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, filter_input(INPUT_POST,'reference'));
$addedby=$_SESSION['mysesi'];
if($libsemno === '1'){
$res = ("INSERT into `waiver_tut` (roll_id, wt1, wt2, wt3, wt4, wt5, wt6, wt7, wt8, addedby, reference) VALUES ('$roll', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee','$addedby', '$reference')");
}
if($libsemno === '2'){
$res = ("INSERT into `waiver_tut` (roll_id, wt1, wt2, wt3, wt4, wt5, wt6, wt7, wt8, addedby, reference) VALUES ('$roll', '0', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee','$addedby', '$reference')");
}
if($libsemno === '3'){
$res = ("INSERT into `waiver_tut` (roll_id, wt1, wt2, wt3, wt4, wt5, wt6, wt7, wt8, addedby, reference) VALUES ('$roll', '0', '0', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee','$addedby', '$reference')");
}
if($libsemno === '4'){
$res = ("INSERT into `waiver_tut` (roll_id, wt1, wt2, wt3, wt4, wt5, wt6, wt7, wt8, addedby, reference) VALUES ('$roll', '0', '0', '0', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee','$addedby', '$reference')");
}
if($libsemno === '5'){
$res = ("INSERT into `waiver_tut` (roll_id, wt1, wt2, wt3, wt4, wt5, wt6, wt7, wt8, addedby, reference) VALUES ('$roll', '0', '0', '0', '0', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee','$addedby', '$reference')");
 }
 if($libsemno === '6'){
$res = ("INSERT into `waiver_tut` (roll_id, wt1, wt2, wt3, wt4, wt5, wt6, wt7, wt8, addedby, reference) VALUES ('$roll', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee','$addedby', '$reference')");
}
if($libsemno === '7'){
$res = ("INSERT into `waiver_tut` (roll_id, wt1, wt2, wt3, wt4, wt5, wt6, wt7, wt8, addedby, reference) VALUES ('$roll', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '$libtutfee', '$libtutfee','$addedby', '$reference')");
}
if($libsemno === '8'){
$res = ("INSERT into `waiver_tut` (roll_id, wt1, wt2, wt3, wt4, wt5, wt6, wt7, wt8, addedby, reference) VALUES ('$roll', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '$libtutfee','$addedby', '$reference')");
}
if($libsemno === '0'){
$res = ("INSERT into `waiver_tut` (roll_id, wt1, wt2, wt3, wt4, wt5, wt6, wt7, wt8, addedby, reference) VALUES ('$roll', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0','$addedby', '$reference')");
}
if ($dbcon->query($res) === TRUE) {
do something
```

Please help to convert the query....

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve, this peace of code creates a single query depending on the $libsemno value already.

Comment: You actually have single query - not 9. But if you want to simplify it a bit, you can use case, put some values to variables and in the final string building query, put those variables instead of your `0`s.

Comment: wt1, wt2, wt3, wt4, wt5, wt6, wt7, wt8 - this looks like a denormalised data structure to me. If you add more WTs in future (whatever they are) then you'll need a new column, and have to completely alter all your code. Whereas if you have a sub-table to hold these, and write the code properly, you can add as many or as few as you like without the code caring. And you could default the field to "0" so you don't have to set a value in the case where that's needed. BTW storing numbers as strings is a bad idea too. Store numbers using numeric columns.

Comment: if its the right process then okey, but if there any easy process then suggest me with example.